# c# Reading data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have problems with understandig, how to read data from XML.
XML looks like this:

```
<PosXML version="7.2.0">
    <ReadCardResponse>
        <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
        <Card>
            <Pan>222300******5062</Pan>
            <Expires>****</Expires>
            <CardName>MASTERCARD</CardName>
            <CardSource>2</CardSource>
        </Card>
    </ReadCardResponse>
</PosXML>
```

I have loaded XML from stream:

```
XDocument doc;
using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    doc= XDocument.Load(responseStream);
}
```

Tried this, but it's not working:

```
XElement returnCode = doc.XPathSelectElement("ReturnCode")
```

Comment: The XPath `ReturnCode` is not valid. With your XML the XPath should be something like (untested) `ReadCardResponse\ReturnCode`. You could check the XPath doc for more complex XPath queries

Comment: Read through [XPath Expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp). XPath expressions can be used to select any node or attribute. You can then use `SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode` with XPath Expression to the node you want to read.

Answer (score 3):

```
var returnCode = doc.XPathSelectElement(@"PosXML/ReadCardResponse/ReturnCode");
```

You need to use the full path to the element

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
XElement returnCode = doc.Element("ReadCardResponse").Element("ReturnCode")
```

You can also access elements by `XPath`, `nodes`, or some `linq` query. Try to play around with intellisense of your IDE